# Flask-SocketIO in Webpack, can't get messages from server back to client

Tags: python, flask, webpack, websocket, webpack-dev-server

When I'm using just plain Flask `FLASK_APP=web_server.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0` for development purposes, I can receive messages from the client (http and websocket). When I want to send messages back after an event, they don't seem to be received by the browser. I'm not sure where they're going. I have a feeling it's my Webpack config because I'm using npm to start the front-end development server which is on port 3000 and I'm wondering if flask-socketio knows how to send messages back. Does anyone see anything wrong with this off the top of their head?

```
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: port,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '**': 'http://0.0.0.0:5001/'
    }
  },
```

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ['FLASK_LOGIN_SECRET_KEY']
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*', async_mode='eventlet')
socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had the socket.io run like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

When I ran the app like this:

```
FLASK_APP=web_server.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

It wouldn't hit the socket.io run line. I launched the app like this instead:

```
python web_server.py
```

I had this proxy:

```
    proxy: {
      'http://localhost:3000': 'http://0.0.0.0:5001/',
      '/socket.io': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5001',
        ws: true
      }
    }
```